# How to join/merge a list of dataframes with common keys in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df1
     uid1  var1
0  John         3
1  Paul         4
2  George       5
```

```
df2
     uid1  var2
0  John         23
1  Paul         44
2  George       52
```

```
df3
     uid1  var3
0  John         31
1  Paul         45
2  George       53
```

```py
df_lst=[df1,df2,df3]
```

How do I merge/join the 3 dataframes in the list based on common key uid1  ?

Edit:
Expected output

```
   df1
     uid1  var1     var2    var3
0  John         3        23      31
1  Paul         4        44      45
2  George       5        52      53
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can join a list of dataframe. Below is the simple example

```
import spark.implicits._
    val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      (0,"John",3),
    (1,"Paul",4),
    (2,"George",5)
    )).toDF("id", "uid1", "var1")

    import spark.implicits._
    val df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      (0,"John",23),
      (1,"Paul",44),
      (2,"George",52)
    )).toDF("id", "uid1", "var2")

    import spark.implicits._
    val df3 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      (0,"John",31),
      (1,"Paul",45),
      (2,"George",53)
    )).toDF("id", "uid1", "var3")


    val df = List(df1, df2, df3)

    df.reduce((a,b) => a.join(b, Seq("id", "uid1")))
```

Output:

```
+---+------+----+----+----+
| id|  uid1|var1|var2|var3|
+---+------+----+----+----+
|  1|  Paul|   4|  44|  45|
|  2|George|   5|  52|  53|
|  0|  John|   3|  23|  31|
+---+------+----+----+----+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope not able to figure out reduce in python

Comment: df.reduce(lambda a,b: a.join(b, ['id', 'uid1']) I think this should help

Comment: pls check the ping in chat room u created

Comment: this answer is in the right direction but doesn't answer the question in pyspark. E.g. "List" and "=>" need to be translated to pyspark

Comment: Its quite late i know, but i was working on something similar now, so this is pyspark version which works for me: 

reduce(lambda a,b: a.join(b, ['id', 'uid1'], how='inner'), df)

Answer (score 4):

Let me suggest python answer:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
SparkContext._active_spark_context.stop()
sc = SparkContext()
sqlcontext = SQLContext(sc)

import pyspark.sql.types as t

rdd_list = [sc.parallelize([('John',i+1),('Paul',i+2),('George',i+3)],1) \
            for i in [100,200,300]]
df_list = []
for i,r in enumerate(rdd_list):
    schema = t.StructType().add('uid1',t.StringType())\
                           .add('var{}'.format(i+1),t.IntegerType())
    df_list.append(sqlcontext.createDataFrame(r, schema))
    df_list[-1].show()
```

```
+------+----+
|  uid1|var1|
+------+----+
|  John| 101|
|  Paul| 102|
|George| 103|
+------+----+

+------+----+
|  uid1|var2|
+------+----+
|  John| 201|
|  Paul| 202|
|George| 203|
+------+----+

+------+----+
|  uid1|var3|
+------+----+
|  John| 301|
|  Paul| 302|
|George| 303|
+------+----+
```

```
df_res = df_list[0]
for df_next in df_list[1:]:
    df_res = df_res.join(df_next,on='uid1',how='inner')
df_res.show()
```

```
+------+----+----+----+
|  uid1|var1|var2|var3|
+------+----+----+----+
|  John| 101| 201| 301|
|  Paul| 102| 202| 302|
|George| 103| 203| 303|
+------+----+----+----+
```

One more option:

```
def join_red(left,right):
    return left.join(right,on='uid1',how='inner')

res = reduce(join_red, df_list)
res.show()
```

```
+------+----+----+----+
|  uid1|var1|var2|var3|
+------+----+----+----+
|  John| 101| 201| 301|
|  Paul| 102| 202| 302|
|George| 103| 203| 303|
+------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will require 1- as many items as you have in the list. In this case it is only 2 joins, but this will destroy performance as this list gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

`Merge` and `join` are two different things in `dataframe`. According to what I understand from your question `join` would be the one

joining them  as

```
df1.join(df2, df1.uid1 == df2.uid1).join(df3, df1.uid1 == df3.uid1)
```

should do the trick but I also suggest to change the `column` names of `df2` and `df3` `dataframes` to  `uid2` and `uid3` so that conflict doesn't arise in the future

Comment: Thanks. but how to do it for a list of dataframes?

Comment: looking at your updated question it seems that you require a merge, which Shankar has answered it.

Comment: join i spark is same as merge in pandas right? Or are they  different?

Comment: I don't think so. join should be same for all the tools. join means joining two or more dataframes with common fields and merge mean union of two or more dataframes having same number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 reduce - analog to koiralos answer:

```
from functools import reduce
from typing import List

from pyspark.sql import DataFrame


dfs: List[DataFrame]

df: DataFrame = reduce(
    lambda left, right: left.join(right, ["key_1", "key_2", ]), 
    dfs
)
```